# Find string NOT preceded by semicolon using Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-negation

In a directory with hundreds of xml-files, I need to find the files which contain the string `nature` where this string is not preceded by a semicolon on the same line.

For example:

It should find:

```
STATUS_OMS.PLUVOI = "NATURE"
```

It should NOT find:

```
; Horse Nature Product..
```

I'm rather new to regular expressions.
I tried a lot, this once seems to come close, but the negation does not have the desired effect.

```
[^;].+?nature
```

Any pointers to what I'm doing wrong?

Please note that I'm using notepad++

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for:

```
^[^;]*nature
```

which looks for a line starting with any number of non-semicolon characters followed by "nature".

Your regex:

```
[^;].+?nature
```

looks for exactly one non-semicolon character anywhere in a line, followed by one or more characters of any kind, followed by "nature".

Comment: Indeed, true as well. Thanks for the explanation of what my own regex was looking for, that helps in the learning process ;)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean? It searches for lines up to and including the word nature that do not have a ; character before the word nature.

```
^[^;]+nature
```

Comment: Awesome. Such a little difference in the expression, a whole new world of results. Thanks a lot!

Comment: svinja has a better one. Mine requires at least one character before the word nature, his does not.

Comment: You are right. Thanks anyway for the quick response. Yours was good enough for my purpose, but for future reference I switched the answer to Svinja.